# ps/2 to usb connector not taking simultaneous input

Tags: windows, laptop, usb, keyboard

Recently I connected a [ps/2 keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector) to my **laptop**  through `ps/2 to usb connector`.

All worked fine until I tried to play game(GTA 4).

So,basically when I pressed **Up key**(accelerated my car) + **left key**(took left) **simultaneously**,only left key was recognized..So,my car lost acceleration but it was still moving left

So,why does my ps/2-usb connector doesn't work for simultaneous input?
Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

this is not certainly the  problem with the PS/2 to USB connector. Try to changing the keyboard settings to default in the game and then check. Try using the "A" key for the left and then check.

Comment: i had also tried A+W key but it didn't work

Comment: do it works fine with other windows application?

Comment: yes the ps/2 keyboard works fine on other systems

Comment: i meant the other applications like winword or in system bios of same PC.

Comment: yes it works fine

Comment: this is something related to game configuration only....

Comment: hmm...i guess u r right

Comment: you can try resetting the keyboard configuration in the controller menu of that game.